# C++ EXC_BAD_ACCESS what does it mean?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to write my first neural network in C++ and I'm having trouble with it.
Basically I get

> segmentation fault 11

So I tried to debug and it turned out that after the line 41 the program stops for a reason called

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS,

what does it mean? how can I turn around it? I've seen from other posts that segmentation fault means running out of stack, which would be an issue because that's maybe the 30% of the code that I planned to write

anyway here is my code, I put in the comment what was line 41 (see comment)

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <cassert>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct Connection
{
    double w;
    double dw;
};

class Neuron;

typedef vector<Neuron> Layer;
//*************************** class Neuron ***************
class Neuron
{
public:
    Neuron(unsigned numOutput, unsigned MyIndex);
    void setOtpuVal(double Val){m_outputVal = Val; }
    double getOutputval(void) const {return m_outputVal; }
    void feedForward (const Layer &prevLayer);

private:
    static double randomWeight(void) {return (rand()/(RAND_MAX));}
    unsigned  m_MyIndex;
    double m_outputVal;
    vector<Connection> m_outputWeights;

};
void Neuron::feedForward (const Layer &prevLayer){

    double sum = 0.0; //<===================================that's line 40
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < prevLayer.size(); ++i)
    {
        sum += prevLayer[i].getOutputval() * prevLayer[i].m_outputWeights[m_MyIndex].w; 
    }
}



Neuron::Neuron(unsigned numOutput, unsigned MyIndex){

for (unsigned c = 0; c < numOutput; ++c)
    {
        m_outputWeights.push_back(Connection());
        m_outputWeights.back().w = randomWeight();
    }

    m_MyIndex = MyIndex;

}





//*************************** class Net    *********************
class Net{

    public:
        Net (const vector<unsigned> &Topology);
        void feedForward(const vector<double> &Input );
        void backProp (const vector<double> &Target){};
        void getResults(vector<double> &Output) const{}; //const non modifica l'oggetto
    private:
        std::vector<Layer> m_layer; // m_layer []   

};

void Net::feedForward (const vector<double> &Input ) {

//assert(Input.size() == m_layer[0].size()-1);
// assert(inputVals.size() == m_layers[0].size() - 1);

    //feeding
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Input.size()-1; ++i) {
        m_layer [0] [i].setOtpuVal(Input[i]);

    }

    //foorward propagatin
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < m_layer.size(); ++i)
    {
        Layer &prevLayer = m_layer[i-1];
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < m_layer[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            m_layer[i][j].feedForward(prevLayer);   
        }
    }
}
Net::Net (const vector<unsigned> &Topology){

    unsigned numLayer = Topology.size();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < numLayer; ++i)
    {
        m_layer.push_back(Layer());
        unsigned numOutput = i == Topology.size() - 1 ? 0 : Topology[i +1]; //inportante!!!!
        for (unsigned j = 0; j <= Topology[i]; ++j)
        {
            m_layer.back().push_back(Neuron(numOutput,j));
            cout<<"made a Neuron"<<endl;
        }
    }

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    ifstream reader("Istruzioni.txt",ios::in);
    std::vector<double> Input;
    std::vector<double> Target;
    std::vector<double> Output;
    std::vector<unsigned> Topology;

    Topology.push_back(3);
    Topology.push_back(2);
    Topology.push_back(1);
    Net MyNet(Topology);


    char letter;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        reader.get(letter);
        if (i == 3)
        {
            Target.push_back( (float)letter - 48);
        }
        else 
            Input.push_back((float)letter - 48);

    }
    reader.close();



    MyNet.feedForward (Input);
    MyNet.backProp(Target);
    MyNet.getResults(Output);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That error means you tried to access not yet allocated memory addresses, or trying to write to statically allocated memory, you can't change.

Comment: You should provide a sample input file that reproduces this issue.

Comment: There's definitely too much irrelevant code to reproduce the issue. Boil that down to a [mcve] please.

Comment: `prevLayer[i].m_outputWeights[m_MyIndex].w` -- Change that to `prevLayer[i].m_outputWeights.at(m_MyIndex).w`.  If `m_MyIndex` is out-of-bounds, you will get a `std::out_of_range` exception thrown instead of an access violation.  In addition, `Neuron` has to be a valid instance, otherwise none of the code inside that function is guaranteed to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The error message and behavior is typical for an invalid memory access. It is one of the possible symptom of UB.  So what can be said hereafter is only a probable explanation, but nothing for sure.

Looking at the code, and assuming it was called with a valid `prevLayer` argument:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < prevLayer.size(); ++i)
{
    sum += prevLayer[i].getOutputval() * prevLayer[i].m_outputWeights[m_MyIndex].w; 
}
```

it is with high probability an access out of bounds.  Since i is in principle within bounds, so the trouble come `m_MyIndex`.

What to do ?

- Check if that member is properly initialized.
- Check if its value is positive and that it's smaller than `prevLayer[i].m_outputWeights.size()`
- If this doesn't help solve the issue, it means that some other place in the code messed up (e.g. prevLayer already refers to an object that doesn't exist, or some memory corruption happened before and didn't show any consequence until this moment).